# Entity Framework Connection via Task Scheduler connects as NTAuthority/Anonymous Logon

Tags: c#, entity-framework, authentication, taskscheduler

I have a `Console Application` (`C#`) that connects to a `database` and sends some emails.  It runs fine when a user debug in `Visual Studio`, but when I copy this to a server and run as a Service Account `domain\AcctNotWorking` I get the error below. If I switch the account that runs the Scheduled Task to my `domain\login` it works fine.  Why is the service account trying to login as `NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON` and any ideas how to fix this?  The `domain\AcctNotWorking` is an admin on the server and has the appropriate permissions in `SQL Server`.

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider
>   failed on Open. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open
>   database "MyDatabaseName" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.

```
Connection String:  add name="ApplicationEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ApplicationEntities" .csdl|res://*/ApplicationEntities" .ssdl|res://*/ApplicationEntities" .msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=SQL-Server-Name;initial catalog=DatabaseName;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy, `Integrated Security=True` means the current user will attempt to log into the sql server using their windows identity.  You either have to 1) create a user for the service to run as, and configure the service to run it under this user, then give this user permissions in the database, or 2) create a sql login with a username/password and use that in your connection string.

Here's a starting point to learn about running a service under a user account

[Minimum rights required to run a windows service as a domain account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178633/minimum-rights-required-to-run-a-windows-service-as-a-domain-account)

and here's a starting point for creating sql server logins

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/create-a-login

Although, honestly, that seems overly complex.  All you need to do is login to the server using SSMS and right click on the Security folder and create a new login.  It's pretty clear.  Then you create a user in the database for that login (same process, but the security folder is under the database).  Not too hard.  Then switch `Itengrated Security=True` out for `User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;`

My preference would be to create a user account on the machine that has no rights other than what it needs to run the service, then create a login & user in sql server for this account that is *also* locked down to the bare minimum rights required to function.  Doing this correctly can be relatively complex if you've never done it before.  It is, however, rewarding and will gain you valuable experience you'll use to great effect in your career.

At least, if you go with the quick and dirty sql login method, encrypt your connection string: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89211k9b(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It has to be mentioned though that using SQL logins is not necessarily what you want. Using a domain account is a valid option; it just has to be done properly.

Comment: Depends, but it's generally okay if you do it right, such as using encrypted connection strings https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89211k9b(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Oh, if the option is there, there are case when you want to do that. I didn't mean to say he shouldn't. Just that it's not the only good option. :-)

Comment: True.  It's the quicker option, but not the best. I'd also run under a specific account created for the service which is 100% locked down and has not a lick more rights than it absolutely needs in order to function.  It's just a bit harder to do that than create a sql login and encrypt the connection string.  (edited the answer to add these kinds of concerns and recommendations in)

Comment: Shouldn't it try to login to the sql server as the account the Service Account 'domain\AcctNotWorking' that the Scheduled Task runs as?

Comment: @user8036781 It's starting to sound like this isn't as much a programming issue as it is an infrastructure issue.  Is the database on a remote server?  Are you logging in using NTLM?  You might want to run the application on the database machine instead, which would take many of these other issues out of the equation.

Answer (score 0):

One reason this can happen is if you don't store the user's password with the task. Without a password, the user is unauthenticated, i.e., anonymous, and can't access the database. See if you have the box below checked and, if so, try unchecking it. This is found under Security options on the task's General tab.

[image]